# Pandas. Check if column names are unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing some data to a pandas DataFrame using the `read_excel()` method. The problem is, that my .xlsx file may have some columns with the same names(for example 'gamma' and 'gamma'). I'm not going to work with such data, I'm going to throw an Exception here. But I can't figure out how to check if columns are unique. After doing the import, pandas renames the column with the same name by adding .digit to it at the end and I can't do something like this (`len(list(df.columns)) == len(set(df.columns))`).

**Note:** I can have some cases when the actual column name ends with .digit, so this solution can introduce some bugs, so I can't do `if any(".1" in col for col in df.columns): raise Exception(...)`

```
    alpha   beta    gamma   gamma.1
0   1   9   1   35
1   2   8   543 12
2   3   7   6   45
3   4   6   4   64
4   5   5   2   865
5   6   4   56  235
6   7   3   6   124
7   8   2   2   135
8   9   1   26  767
```

How can I make check for column name duplicates? Thank you.

Comment: `if any(".1" in col for col in df.columns): raise Exception(...)`

Comment: I can have some cases when the actual column name ends with .digit, so this solution can introduce some bugs

Comment: OK then put that into your question. People can't read your mind

Comment: Also include what you have tried so far and any other details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can read your header as regular data with `header = pd.read_excel(..., header=None, nrows=1)` and check for dups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check you could do something like:

EDIT: I did as you asked with only a single read

```py
import openpyxl
def load_df(path, sheet_name):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    lst = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]
    if len(lst) != len(set(lst)):
        raise Exception("foo")

    return pd.DataFrame(ws.values)

df = load_df("data/test.xlsx", "Sheet1")
```

It might be worth keeping an eye on future updates of pandas. If you read the docs it states the following:

```
mangle_dupe_cols: bool, default True

Duplicate columns will be specified as ‘X’, ‘X.1’, …’X.N’, rather than ‘X’…’X’. Passing in False will cause data to be overwritten if there are duplicate names in the columns.
```

> Deprecated since version 1.5.0: Not implemented, and a new argument to
> specify the pattern for the names of duplicated columns will be added
> instead

So in future you'll be able to write simpler code that can handle it.

Comment: Yes, I was quite frustrated when realized that 'mangle_dupe_cols' feature is not present yet

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade I've nothing to hide. Admittedly that single line gave me a chuckle so I used it as a tip of the cap but if you're seriously going to complain about a single line that's as complex as a print statement then I think you need to go touch grass my friend. Our approach to this answer is vastly different

Comment: @Rykari perhaps you don't know the meaning of the ;) emoji? I was joking

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Fair enough, my apologies then, too used to people on this site being... strangely disagreeable people.

Comment: @Rykari can't disagree with you there (pun). I am going to delete my comment, as you are correct -- looking back at it, it may come across as "disagreeable". LOL

Comment: @Rykari FWIW `lst = []; for cell in ws[1]: lst.append(cell.value)` can/should be replaced with list comprehension.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Modified to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Read just your header as normal data and check for duplicates:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None, nrows=1)
if not df.iloc[0].is_unique:
    raise Exception("Duplicates")
```

This requires you opening the file twice. Although, the first time you are only reading one row from it. If you still want to avoid it, you can do this:

```py
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None)

columns = df.iloc[0]
if not columns.is_unique:
    raise Exception("Duplicates")

df.drop(0, inplace=True)
df.columns = columns
```

Comment: Does this mean that I have to open the file twice(for checking(with header=None) and then for actual reading(with headers))? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Rykari why would one need a wrapper function?

Comment: Coz I can't edit my comments, replace "you'd need to" with "could"

Comment: @Rykari just delete it and retype if it's still relevant.